# Ajax rate system with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rating-system

So, I grabbed this code from [here](http://megarush.net/5-star-rating-system-with-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax/). and I changed it a little to fit my db and display the rate based on my idGames, it's working fine, but now I want to do something like [this](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/59429/dark-darker-darkest).

How can I display the rates when I enter in the game page and rate that particular game?
I have an `index.php` page, on which I show all my games, and I have a `gameview.php` that is the path for each game in `index.php`, so when you click in the game in index that game is displayed in gameview. Is there a way to implement that code to rate the games in `gameview.php`? I don't know if I'm being clear enough, but take that link as an example, it's exactly what I want. And I know that `MYSQL` is deprecated, but I don't know `MYSQLi` or `PDO`. So if you can help me with this I appreciate.

```
<?php
include_once('settings.php');
connect();

$query  = "SELECT idGames FROM jogos";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$ids    = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$ids[] = $row['idGames'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
$rating_tableName = 'jogos';
$id               = $ids[$i];

$q = "SELECT total_votes, total_value FROM $rating_tableName WHERE idGames=$id";
$r = mysql_query($q);

if (!$r)
    echo mysql_error();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {

    $v  = $row['total_votes'];
    $tv = $row['total_value'];
    if ($v)
        $rat = $tv / $v;
    else
        $rat = 0;

}

$j  = $ids[$i];
$id = $ids[$i];
echo '<div class="product">
       Rate Item ' . $j . '
        <div id="rating_' . $id . '" class="ratings">';
for ($k = 1; $k < 6; $k++) {
    if ($rat + 1 > $k)
        $class = "star_" . $k . "  ratings_stars ratings_vote";
    else
        $class = "star_" . $k . " ratings_stars ratings_blank";
    echo '<div class="' . $class . '"></div>';
}
echo ' <div class="total_votes"><p class="voted"> Rating:     <strong>' . @number_format($rat) . '</strong>/5 (' . $v . '  vote(s) cast) 
        </div>
    </div></div>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Are you looking for having stars that are partially filled rather then rounding ratings to the nearest full star?

Comment: no, forget about the stars, I'm trying to show the rate system in my gameview.php page so the people can vote on the game. Just it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to retrieve the ratings count with starts. It will display based on your css style.

If you user stars with css background u can this line like this

$ratings = (@round($rs[total_value] / $rs[total_votes],1)) * 20;

I hove it will helpfull.

// Query to retrieve rating per game or article

$query  = "SELECT idGames FROM jogos";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

```
$id = $row['idGames'];

$sql = "SELECT total_votes, total_value FROM $rating_tableName WHERE idGames=$id";

$results = mysql_query($sql);

$rs = mysql_fetch_array($results);

// set clss of star

$ratings = (@round($rs[total_value] / $rs[total_votes],1));


 <div class="product">

    <div id="rating_' . $id . '" class="ratings">

    $class = "star_" . $ratings . " ratings_stars ratings_blank";//stars with css style 

   <div class="' . $class . '"></div>

   Rating: <strong> $ratings / 5 </strong> //  shows count out of 5
```

```
 </div>
```

}

Comment: I wanna say thank you for that, I really appreciate it, but I'm gatting a lot of parse errors, could you format it?

Comment: Because I did't prepared code for that i just told you concept only I hope u can change it.     If you need any help I will help you let me know thanks.